# mylocationButton Not updating My Location why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

As i had used my location button and this methods...

```
[mapView.settings setMyLocationButton:YES];

//AddObserverForDriverCurrentLocation
[mapView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

 [self.view addSubview:mapView];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
});

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:
(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations 
{

NSLog(@"Locations:%@",[locations lastObject]);


}



- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myLocation"]) {
    CLLocation *location = [object myLocation];
    NSLog(@"Location, %@,", location);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D target =
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.7,75.8);

    [mapView animateToLocation:target];
    [mapView animateToZoom:17];
 }
}
```

But when I tap on myLocation button it is not uspdating my location please help

Comment: what the problem faced....

Comment: My mylocation button Not updating my current location.When I move on map and Tap mylocation button Its not dragging me back to my current location on map.

Comment: put the break point and check once the method is called or not

Comment: I had done observeValueForKeypath is not getting called..!!! I had also put the observer in viewdidload ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

To move to your current position you have to:

```
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
```

Then you can setup a key value observer in your `viewWillAppear` Method and then you get your location update with the Location Manager of the GoogleMaps SDK.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Implement here to check if already KVO is implemented.
    ...
    [mapView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: nil]
}
```

And then observe the property.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myLocation"] && [object isKindOfClass:[GMSMapView class]])
    {
        [mapView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: mapView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                                                 longitude: mapView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                                      zoom: mapView.projection.zoom]]; // check that the zoom property once
    }
}
```

Do not forget to deregister your observer in the viewWillDisappear.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    // Implement here if the view has registered KVO
    ...
    [mapView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation"];
}
```

Comment: Anbu Thanks For all The help,I really appraciate your knowledge and you are making good use of it by helping others..Thanks again get back to you soon :]

Comment: tanx a lot if my answer is hopeful please upvote the answer, it is useful for future